# How to extract key/value pairs in JSON body from ResponseEntity in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, http

I am making a GET request to an outside endpoint from within my Spring server. I am using the RestTemplate to create the get request via `exchange()` and storing the response in a ResponseEntity. If the object that was returned from the server looks something like this:

```
[
 {
   "key1" : "value",
   "key2" : "value
 },

 { 
   "key3" : "value"
 }
]
```

how would I access the value of key3 for example?

I am aware of the `toString()` function, however That wont help me parse out a key and value pair.

Comment: Parse the JSON to a list of maps. Take the second item in the list, get the value for `key3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode jsonNode;
  jsonNode = mapper.readTree(your jsonObject)
  jsonNode.findValue("key3")
```

Comment: would this work if I passed the ResponseEntity into the readTree?